# Service 'nginx' failed to build: ... read-only file system

Tags: macos, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm on OS X El Capitan.

The project is [here](https://github.com/realpython/dockerizing-django).

```
➜  docker docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.6.0, build d99cad6
docker-py version: 1.7.0
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014

➜  docker docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.10.2
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   c3959b1
 Built:        Mon Feb 22 22:37:33 2016
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:20:08 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Detailed log:

```
➜  django2 git:(master) docker-compose build
redis uses an image, skipping
postgres uses an image, skipping
Building web
Step 1 : FROM python:3.5-onbuild
3.5-onbuild: Pulling from library/python
51f5c6a04d83: Already exists
65e9ddd8bd7a: Already exists
c41545ebedf5: Already exists
04aed1875617: Already exists
cf8af6bdf113: Already exists
b1dde6937fab: Pull complete
c8bc9f75687c: Pull complete
b8e93735119c: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:64873fca593ef95e3e6ff2759f1be8850e2df13c4abc379c28d876fff80bd491
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.5-onbuild
# Executing 3 build triggers...
Step 1 : COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
Step 1 : RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 72d7552b9c02
Collecting Django==1.8.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading Django-1.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2MB)
Collecting gunicorn==19.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading gunicorn-19.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (110kB)
Collecting psycopg2==2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.tar.gz (367kB)
Collecting redis==2.10.3 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading redis-2.10.3.tar.gz (86kB)
Installing collected packages: Django, gunicorn, psycopg2, redis
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'done'
  Running setup.py install for redis: started
    Running setup.py install for redis: finished with status 'done'
Successfully installed Django-1.8.1 gunicorn-19.3.0 psycopg2-2.6 redis-2.10.3
Step 1 : COPY . /usr/src/app
 ---> f802f2dfd11d
Removing intermediate container 5bb1297979d0
Removing intermediate container 72d7552b9c02
Removing intermediate container 95570b5a7fd9
Successfully built f802f2dfd11d
Building nginx
Step 1 : FROM tutum/nginx
latest: Pulling from tutum/nginx
faecf96fd5ab: Downloading [==================================================>] 28.36 MB/28.36 MB
995977506e98: Download complete
efb63fb8dcb6: Download complete
a3ed95caeb02: Download complete
fc9f65f1d092: Download complete
a69b26be3eeb: Download complete
292e9d346afc: Download complete
2642b1ce8f09: Download complete
ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: write /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob730892159: read-only file system
```

Comment: Do you think you hard disk is full. Try `df -h`

Comment: No, there are more 500gb available space in my iMac

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13288

Comment: Thanks @Michael but the issue is closed, it's a dead end

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: write /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob730892159: read-only file system

Take a look for the 'mount' output, is your /mnt/sda1 directory mounted with read-only option?

Try to run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /mnt/sda1
```